# How can I get the number of working days by comparing two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have 3 tables, a table storing task details, a table storing staff details and the task assignment as below.

TASKS

| TASK_ID | TASK_START_DATE | TASK_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 03-04-2021 | 05-04-2021 |
| 002 | 05-04-2021 | 07-04-2021 |

STAFFS

| STAFF_ID | STAFF_WORK_DAY |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, FRIDAY |
| 1002 | MONDAY, TUESDAY |

TASK_ASSIGNMENT

| STAFF_ID | TASK_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 001 |
| 1002 | 002 |

I extracted the dates for each tasks and converted them into week day names using TO_CHAR

| TASK_ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | SATURDAY |
| 001 | SUNDAY |
| 001 | MONDAY |
| 002 | MODNDAY |
| 002 | TUESDAY |
| 002 | WEDNESDAY |

How can I compare the tables and find out the number of working days for each task in its duration?

Expected result

| TASK_ID | STAFF_ID | COUNT(WORK_DAY) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1001 | 1 |
| 002 | 1002 | 2 |

Comment: Could you add the output that you are expecting as a result?

Comment: I have put the table there. E.G. STAFF 1002 works on MON and TUE. So in the duration of TASK 002, there will be 2 working days.

Comment: I'd consider a separate staff_works table, with one row per work day for each employee.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
WITH days ( id, day ) AS (
  SELECT 0, 'MONDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'TUESDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'WEDNESDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'THURSDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'FRIDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'SATURDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'SUNDAY' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.task_id,
       s.staff_id,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   staff s
       INNER JOIN days d
       ON ( s.staff_work_day LIKE '%' || d.day || '%' )
       INNER JOIN task_assignment ta
       ON ( ta.staff_id = s.staff_id )
       INNER JOIN tasks t
       ON ( ta.task_id = t.task_id )
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT t.TASK_START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 AS task_day
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.TASK_END_DATE - t.TASK_START_DATE + 1
       ) td
       ON ( td.task_day - TRUNC( td.task_day, 'IW' ) = d.id )
GROUP BY t.task_id, s.staff_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks ( TASK_ID, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_END_DATE ) AS
SELECT '001', DATE '2021-04-03', DATE '2021-04-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '002', DATE '2021-04-05', DATE '2021-04-07' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE STAFF( STAFF_ID, STAFF_WORK_DAY ) AS
SELECT 1001, 'MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, FRIDAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 'MONDAY, TUESDAY' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TASK_ASSIGNMENT( STAFF_ID, TASK_ID ) AS
SELECT 1001, '001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, '002' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TASK_ID | STAFF_ID | COUNT(*) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 002 | 1002 | 2 |
> | 001 | 1001 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=afaa0ef2adf9021a8cbbccc287698c61)*

Comment: it turns out no row is being selected

Comment: @WayneSum Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67209886/edit) your question with a [MRE] including DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for you tables and DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data so that we can replicate the issue. As you can see, my query works on db<>fiddle and just stating that "no row is being selected" does not help us to debug the issue as we cannot replicate what you have done.